# Real Camera Perspective Projection

Tags: ios, matlab, opencv, computer-vision

I'm working on a project that will be used to track robots on a plane using OpenCV. Currently I'm trying to simply obtain the pixel coordinates of a 3D point, but for some reason I am getting impossible values; negative values and numbers exceeding the rows or columns of pixels. I am using a iPhone X for the camera and the image processing, however I have been testing the matrix transformations in MATLAB for speed and simplicity.

My question: Why am I getting large values, exceeding the number of rows and columns of pixels, and why are there negative values? What have I done wrong with the coordinate systems, translations or MATLAB implementation?

In order to obtain the intrinsic calibration matrix I used [this](http://www.vision.caltech.edu/bouguetj/calib_doc/) MATLAB calibration tool provided by Caltech.

The intrinsic calibration matrix:

[image]

I am fairly confident this is correct, as I performed the calibration 3 times, with different sets of chessboard images, and achieved very similar results each time. Furthermore, the focal length values are close to those I found online from calculating the focal length from FOV and sensor size.

The equation for calculating the pixel coordinates in projective space, P^2, from world space in R^3 is as follows: [image]

In the form of:

[image]

Where:

s - Scale factor

m` - pixel coordinates in P^2

A - Intrinsic camera matrix

[R|t] - concatenated camera rotation and translation. The extrinsic matrix.

M` - The physical point homogeneous coordinates.

The diagram below shows the coordinate convention:[image]

For simplicity and ease of my calculations, I have applied no rotation to the camera, so the image plane and physical plane the point is on is parallel. Therefore my rotation matrix R is the 3x3 identity matrix.

The point I am trying to convert to pixel coordinates is a red circle on the centre of a table. I have defined the coordinate system origin as at the bottom left, as shown in the diagram below. The z axis is positive 'into' the page.[image: Top down view of table, showing coordinate system]

I am positioning the camera centre to be exactly 510 mm above the red circle. So with world space coordinates of (1000, -1500, -510). This leads to the extrinsic matrix:

[image]

Leading to the final equation to find pixel coordinates (u, v). I divide the left hand side of the equation by 510 to obtain u and v.

[image]

Below is my MATLAB implementation of the maths:

```
clear all;
clc;

theta = 0;

Rx = [1,          0,           0; %With theta = 0 , this is the 3x3 identity matrix
      0, cos(theta), -sin(theta);
      0, sin(theta), cos(theta)];

tx = 1000; %Camera translations. ty and tz are negative due to coordinate system convention.
ty = -1500;
tz = -510;
I = eye(3);
translation = [tx; ty; tz];

extrinsic = [Rx translation]; %Concatenate rotation and translation matrices


fx = 3319.68707;
fy = 3337.51214;
cx = 1476.77578;
cy = 1921.59370;
intrinsic = [fx,   0,  cx; 
              0,  fy,  cy; 
              0,   0,  1];

x = 1000;
y = -1500;
z = 0;
worldCoords = [x; y; z; 1];


scaledPixelCoords = intrinsic * extrinsic * worldCoords; %Before I divide the LHS by 510

pixelCoords = scaledPixelCoords / 510;

disp(pixelCoords);
```

Output:

```
    1.0e+04 *

        1.1542
       -2.1554
       -0.0001
```

I am new to this subject and am not sure if I have necessarily defined the translations, or world coordinates correctly.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @AnderBiguri What is wrong with my process or values I am using such that I get negative answers and answers a whole order of magnitude too large.

Comment: Why did you put negative `tz` in the extrinsic matrix? Camera Z-axis is pointing forward. Recall that the extrinsic matrix allows transforming a point expressed in the world frame to the camera frame. So the translation part of the extrinsic matrix is actually the position of the world frame in the camera frame.

Comment: @Catree Thank you, I changed the translation values to fit that description. Such that tx = -1000, ty = 1500 and tz = 510. Is this correct. The output is now all positive, and the the values of u and v are equal to cx and cy respectively.